# Установка Postgresql 9.4 на Centos 7 с нужной локалью

Tags: postgresql, centos

Устанавливаю на centos7 postgresql9.4 вот [по этой инструкции](http://www.unixmen.com/postgresql-9-4-released-install-centos-7/).

В целом всё ставится, но не устраивают кодировки которые идут по умолчанию:

```
Encoding SQL_ASCII
Collate  С
Ctype    C
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может где конфиги поправить или во время

```
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgresql94-setup initdb
```

Что-то указать ?

Comment: --encoding=UTF8 --locale=ru_RU.UTF-8

Comment: @norbornen Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это стандартные ключи initdb, но я не уверен в полноте и правильности ответа так как никогда не пользовался postgresql94-setup для установки СУБД

Answer (score 1):

ответ из комментария:

---

```
/usr/pgsql-9.4/bin/postgresql94-setup initdb --encoding=UTF8 --locale=ru_RU.UTF-8
```